# How to create new next js project

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am new with `Next.JS` and try to create `React` app with `Next.JS` with this command `npx create-next-app@latest landing-page`.

[image]

After put the detail of the project, the command finish with some warning.

[image]

When the project is created, I try to run `npm run dev`, but nothing happen, it should be run the project in `hhtp://localhost:3000`.

[image]

Is there any step that I have missed? Or something wrong my development configuration?
Thank you guys.

Comment: try running using "yarn dev" command, if still not run please share your package.json file

Comment: You should have read documentation first https://nextjs.org/docs#system-requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update your node version.

Comment: Nice, after update my npm version to v18.16.0, the development server can start. Thank you man.

Comment: Perhaps this link can help,
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/48277